# GetVolumeInformation() not reporting FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME for a locked SD Card without any file-system

Tags: c, windows

I'm getting some strange results when checking if an SD Card is locked using the `FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME` file-system flag reported by [`GetVolumeInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx).

If the SD Card is locked, and the SD Card contains a volume with a file-system, then the flag is correctly set, however if there is no file-system, the flag is not set, even though Windows correctly reports the drive as read-only.

[image: disk management screenshot]

```
const wchar_t letter = "F";
DWORD filesystemFlags = 0;

TCHAR drivePath[kVolumePathShortLength];
sprintf_s(drivePath, "%c:\\", letter);

const HRESULT result = GetVolumeInformation(drivePath, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &filesystemFlags, NULL, 0);

if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
  if (filesystemFlags & FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME) {
    printf("Drive is read-only\n");
  } else {
    printf("Drive is not read-only\n");
  }
}
```

Since the code works fine if there is a file-system in the volume, I'm thinking there might be other way Disk Management checks if a volume is read-only or not, that works regardless of the file-system.

Comment: IMO the removable drive F is not really "Read Only" here, because if there is no file system on it it can't actually even been read.

Comment: Disk Management and Explorer complain about even formatting F because its read-only, so I think there is a distinction even beyond an existing file-system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetVolumeInformation` applies to volumes, not disks. `GetVolumeInformation` also returns a BOOL, not a HRESULT so you cannot trust the output of your sample code!

You can try getting low-level disk information:

```
for (UINT d = 'A'; d <= 'Z'; ++d) // Real code should use GetLogicalDrives
{
    WCHAR devbuf[20];
    wsprintfW(devbuf, L"\\\\.\\%c:", d);
    HANDLE hDev = CreateFileW(devbuf, 0, 7, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) continue;
    DWORD cb, gle;
    BOOL succ = DeviceIoControl(hDev, IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITABLE, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &cb, NULL);
    gle = GetLastError();
    printf("%c: is %s (error %u)\n", d, succ ? "writable" : gle == ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT ? "read-only" : "unknown", succ ? 0 : gle);
    CloseHandle(hDev);
}
```

This is what Windows file systems do according to [this thread](http://osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=218390) @ OSR:

> ... the in-box file systems send IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITEABLE to determine whether the disk is read-only or not.

You could also try [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706681(v=vs.85).aspx) but I would guess that flag is the same thing as `IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITABLE`.

[This thread](http://osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=218390) claims that `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_GPT_ATTRIBUTES` can be sent to all disk types but I don't see why this would be a better choice.

Comment: And just to be clear, a mounted file system volume can be read-only even if the disk is writable so you need to check both if you want information about volumes **and** disks.

Comment: ...and finally, [this thread](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=70402) indicates that `FILE_READ_ONLY_DEVICE` is not reliable so there is no point in looking for [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563818(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Works great, thank a lot for the fix, and the heads up regarding the return value of `GetVolumeInformation`.