# Null when accessing the Access property of a Win32_Volume instance

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi

As a way to resolve [GetVolumeInformation() not reporting FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME for a locked SD Card without any file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703463/1641422), I found that the [`Win32_Volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx) class has an `Access` `uint16` property that:

> Describes whether the media is readable. This property is inherited from CIM_StorageExtent. This can be one of the following values.

I'm interacting with WMI from a C++ program, so when reading the `Access` property I get a [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx) structure with the result.

According to the docs, a `VARIANT` contains an `union`, so I should first check the `vt` property to determine its type. `vt` is a [`VARTYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/vartype-function), which is an `int` according to the docs. The `vt` value I get after accessing the `Access` property is `1`, which again according to the docs, is null. I can confirm this result by trying to access most of the `union` members, which are not set at all.

Here's a complete runnable example (run with `cl /EHsc test.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  IWbemLocator *locator = NULL;
  IWbemServices *services = NULL;
  IEnumWbemClassObject* enumerator = NULL;
  IWbemClassObject *classObject = NULL;

  if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED))) return 1;
  if (FAILED(CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL))) return 1;
  if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&locator))) return 1;
  if (FAILED(locator->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &services))) return 1;
  if (FAILED(CoSetProxyBlanket(services, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE))) return 1;
  if (FAILED(services->ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume"), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &enumerator))) return 1;

  while (enumerator) {
    ULONG code = 0;
    if (FAILED(enumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &classObject, &code))) return 1;
    if (code == 0) break;

    VARIANT variant;
    if (FAILED(classObject->Get(L"DriveLetter", 0, &variant, NULL, NULL))) return 1;
    if (variant.bstrVal == NULL) {
      VariantClear(&variant);
      classObject->Release();
      continue;
    };

    std::wcout << " DriveLetter : " << variant.bstrVal[0] << std::endl;

    VariantClear(&variant);
    if (FAILED(classObject->Get(L"Access", 0, &variant, NULL, NULL))) return 1;
    std::wcout << "Access VARTYPE -> " << variant.vt << std::endl;

    VariantClear(&variant);
    classObject->Release();
  }

  enumerator->Release();
  services->Release();
  locator->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

This is an example output from my system (Windows 10 Pro x86_64):

```
 DriveLetter : C
Access VARTYPE -> 1
 DriveLetter : F
Access VARTYPE -> 1
 DriveLetter : E
Access VARTYPE -> 1
```

I can access other string properties, like `DriveLetter`, just fine, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong with this particular property.

**UPDATE 1:** Looks like I get the same results with *any* `uint16` property, but not with `uint32`, nor `uint64`, which seem to work just fine.

Comment: you confuse disk (and information returned about it from storage device stack) and volume on it and information returned from mounted it file system. in picture - **disk** is read only. and this info get from storage device stack. and absolute no sense use  WMI here - how you think WMI server get info which returned to you ? only by some ioctls to device. so why not direct send this ioctls yourself ? this will be much more effective and simply

Comment: This code is leaking lots of memory if things go bad. You should use the [Compiler COM Support Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa234608.aspx) that are in `comdef.h`.  You are already using `_bstr_t`, but you should be using `_com_ptr_t` and `_variant_t` as well.

Comment: You are also not using the `pvtType` output parameter of `IWbemClassObject::Get()`. If the variant is empty, the parameter should be outputting `CIM_EMPTY`, which would be a definitive indicator that `Access` really is empty. It should be outputting `CIM_UINT16` if `Access` exists. For that matter, you might also consider not exiting the app if `Get()` returns `WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND`, since that is not really a fatal error. You can use `IWbemClassObject::GetNames()` to get an array of names that can be used with `Get()`

Comment: I was able to reproduce your same results on my Win7 x64 system.  `IWbemClassObject::GetNames()` lists `Access` is present, but `Get("Access")` returns a null variant, though the `pvtType` parameter returns `CIM_UINT16`. So `Access` really is a uint16, but its value is not available.